# add class attribute dynamically, the added class should change based on user action

Tags: angularjs

I want to add class to a particular element, the added class should change based on user action. I can't use ng-class hence I am using ng-attr-class. Please check the [Plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/tPmmduXcF73U0A33wkZz). Here I want to change color of the div to red when user selects the provided radio button. Any suggestions

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input type="radio" ng-bind = "enable"/> Enable
<div style="min-height:50px; min-width: 200px; border:1px solid black;" ng-attr-class = "{{enable && 'divEnabled' || 'divDisabled'}}"></div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

.divEnabled{ background-color:#FF0000;}

.divDisabled{background-color:#00FF00;}
```

I am using Angular 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two ways to toggle the `div` background color:

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yHipwWWeXbpQTw4DUDcE?p=preview)

1. use two radio buttons,

   ```
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="true" ng-model = "enable"/>Enable
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="false" ng-model = "enable"/> Disable
    <div style="min-height:50px; min-width: 200px; border:1px solid black;" ng-attr-class = "{{enable == 'true' && 'divEnabled' || 'divDisabled'}}"></div>
   ```
2. use one checkbox button:

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model = "enable"/> 
   <div style="min-height:50px; min-width: 200px; border:1px solid black;" ng-attr-class = "{{enable && 'divEnabled' || 'divDisabled'}}"></div>
   ```